# Insert only non null values into SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, talend

I try to insert values into my table, but I want to only insert the non null ones, the null values I need to just ignore no treatment needed. The variable I want to insert is a result of a SQL select, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
insert into mytable(id)
values (case when (select id from tab2 where login=?) is not null then (select id from tab2 where login=?))
```

In other words, I want to insert the id's that correspond to this condition and that are not null only.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it :

```
insert into mytable(id)
select id from tab2 
where login=? and id is not null
```

Comment: sadly doesnt work,got the samemessage:ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: If you just run the select statement what does it return?

Comment: itgives nothing just empty column with name id the problem in the insert it still gives ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint  even with the condition not null

Comment: @Rana - see this fiddle , it works , your issue is something else *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=741ed2e02da54a6a05f31a3481ae701a)*

Comment: actually when you insert shoudnt you add values ()? instead you just add a select

Comment: @rana no. it either you are inserting values directly using values () or selecting from another table

Comment: it works but the pb is i want to also insert another var (no condition this time) in same table so i tried this and got an error thats why i prefer values but with values the not null condition doesnt work : 
select id_compte from utilisateur
where login=? and id_compte is not null
select id_groupe from groupe 
where code_groupe = ?
"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one and see if that works for you:

```
insert into mytable(id)
select ID
from tab2
where id IS NOT NULL
  and login = ?
```

Comment: didnt work ERROR: null value in column "id_compte" violates not-null constraint